# Instância de conexão banco de dados

Tags: java, conexão, singleton

Galera,
Tenho um problema que é o seguinte, minha classe de conexão ao banco de dados é um Singleton. Ocorre que se o servidor cair a instância da classe não sabe que o servidor caiu, só sei quando, por exemplo, tento executar um resultset daí dá exceção.
Como posso fazer para que a instancia da classe de conexão saiba que o servidor caiu?

Answer (score 0):

Eu não compreendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas creio que posso te ajudar mostrando como eu fazia a minha conexão com meu Banco de Dados via JDBC Java.

```
package com.mypet.MyPet.persistence;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConectionMySql {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/MyPet?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
    private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String LOGIN = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "toor";
    public static Connection connection;

    private ConectionMySql(){}

    public static void openConection(){
        try{
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            ConectionMySql.connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL, LOGIN, PASSWORD);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void closeConection(){
        try {
            if(!ConectionMySql.connection.isClosed()){
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Essa é minha classe que eu faço a conexão com o Banco MySQL, possuo um metodo de abrir e fechar a conexão com o banco, dando um `try catch`.

Sempre quando eu vou fazer alguma chamada no banco via Java, eu abro a conexão com o metodo `openConection` e fecho com o `closeConection`, assim, caso de qualquer erro na conexão a aplicação estará ciente, pois, sempre abre e fecha antes de cada chamada.

```
public T insert(T object) {
        ConectionMySql.openConection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) ConectionMySql.connection.prepareStatement(insertSQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            this.setStatementValuesToInsert(preparedStatement, object);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (resultSet.next()){
                object = this.prepareObjectToResponse(resultSet.getLong(1), object);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            ConectionMySql.closeConection();
        }
        return object;
    }
```

Onde você pode ver o `ConectionMySql.openConection();` e no finally o `ConectionMySql.closeConection();`.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma maneira, caso queira, pode acessar o código acima em meu [GitHub](https://github.com/RhianLopes) no projeto escolar [MyPet](https://github.com/RhianLopes/MyPet/tree/master/MyPet), feito o Back em Java com Spring e JDBC.

Comment: É que no meu caso eu usei um Singleton, ou seja, só instancio a classe de conexão uma única vez. Ocorre que quando faço o getConnection retorna a instancia mas pode ser que o banco caiu.